# In arm assembly, is the stack a separate memory unit or a partition of the main memory?

Tags: assembly, memory, arm, stack

I always have this confusion,in arm assembly, is the stack a separate memory unit or a partition of the main memory itself?

In my understanding,the main memory(RAM) is divided into stack and heap.The stack is pointed by the stack pointer `R13` register or `sp`.From this pointer we can do the stack operations.

Also what I understand is that stack stores local variables in high level languages and function calls.How does it translate to assembly?

I am not able to find the answers to these questions on google.

Comment: It's just part of main memory.  "stack" vs. "heap" is only about how you choose to use it, not hardware.  "the heap" isn't even a real thing; dynamic memory allocation is usually not contiguous in modern systems.  If you want to see asm, look at compiler output for example: https://godbolt.org/ [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116).

Comment: @PeterCordes thank you!So stack would just be a part of the main memory and we access then using the stack pointer then right?

Comment: Yeah, that's all, nothing special.

Comment: @PeterCordes thank you.If you would write it as an answer,I can mark it as the solution.

Comment: There are some good canonical answers that say this (among other things) on [What and where are the stack and heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/79936/224132), so fortunately I don't need to spend time writing something worthy of being a full answer.

Comment: For good measure, I threw in some other duplicate links, take a look at the list of duplicates.

Comment: @PeterCordes thank you.The third link answers my question completely.

Comment: the arm documentation can be found through google.

Comment: heap is a high level software notion it is not related to hardware.